# C++11 thread_pool, futures, promises support in gcc

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

**Is any of [N2276](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2276.html) supported in gcc yet?**

I am currently using 4.6.1, where `std::thread` seems to be working ok.

If not, should I be using [boost's threadpool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839631/boost-threadpool)?

**What is a good alternative/stopgap that allows for easy transition to an eventual futures, promises, and thread_pool?**

Maybe [this](http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/) would work?

It looks like N2276 isn't listed [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html).  I wonder if any of N2276's features are going to make it in - I thought I read about **futures** and **promises** and other paradigms going into C++11: will have to google around and see what's going on.

Comment: Is there `std::thread_pool` really?! Honestly, I never knew that!

Comment: Have you had a look here: http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html  and  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x

Comment: Boost doesn't have thread pool, or have I missed something?

Comment: @JaredKrumsie +1 that second link to libstdc++ is useful - I will edit the OP to ask for viable alternatives

Comment: There is no `std::thread_pool`. It did not become part of the standard.

Comment: `std::thread_pool` have been removed from the standard before finalize. Maybe next time it can get into C++2x

Comment: @J-16SDiZ: Don't just dismiss TR2, it may very well be added there. Same with filesystem.

Comment: @J-16SDiZ +1 rofl - I can't wait 10 years for the next release - will start looking for viable alternatives!

Comment: @J-16SDiZ And you really believe in that 2 before the x?

Comment: @ChristianRau can you believe the 0 in C++0x ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [gcc C++ library status page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x) shows much of this is implemented: `thread, packaged_task, future, promise` are mostly in.  As noted by others `<threadpool>` didn't make it in.

The TR2 library enhancement process is supposed to start in January.  I would expect thread pools and many other things to be proposed very soon.

Comment: Thx for the summary - the pseudo-boost threadpool mentioned in the link in the OP seems like a decent alternative until it is actually added to the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Poco library's [threadpool](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.ThreadPool.html) implementation and Zthread's [Executor](http://zthread.sourceforge.net/html/classZThread_1_1Executor.html) are respected alternatives to boost threadpool.

Comment: You might want to know, that StackOverflow Netiquette encourages high quality posts and as such, you shall rather post you answer and code elements instead of link-only derrogations. Kindly update your post to show your will to comply with the rules and to provide a persistent content of your answer for cases the referred URL becomes un-retrievable in some future re-organisation et al